# Python Tkinter: Mi imagen .png sale con un fondo blanco

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de musica, y edite una imagen sin derechos de autor, le quite el fondo y la hice una imagen .png; Luego de eso cargue la imagen usando PIL (Pillow para Tkinter):

```
# Este seria el boton de "play"
playI = Image.open('assets/play.png')
playI = playI.resize((80, 80))
window.playI = ImageTk.PhotoImage(playI)
```

Cree el boton para reproducir la musica, su `.pack()` y su `.place()`:

```
playB = Button(window, height=80, width=80,image=window.playI, bd=0)
playB.pack()
playB.place(x=355, y= 400)
```

El problema es que la imagen salia asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El boton de play salia con un fondo blanco, pero es .png ¿Como hago que la imagen no tenga ningun fondo, osea que el fondo sea transparente?

Saludos

Comment: Cuando cargas una imagen transparente con Tkinter, puedes definir de que color será la parte transparente cambiando el color de fondo del widget, pero no se puede tener una autentica transparencia...

Comment: No hay ninguna manera? Alguna alternativa o algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solución

Cuando me preguntaste en los comentarios si había alguna alternativa, lo pensé y llegué a la conclusión de que si! Existe una alternativa!

Puedes crear imágenes en un canvas, que si tolera la transparencia. Pero por supuesto, una imagen en un canvas NO es un botón, por lo que tendrás que crear tu propio "widget Button" para el canvas.
Aquí te dejo algo hecho. Cualquier cosa que quieras agregar, es tarea para la casa:

```
from tkinter import *

v = Tk()

class CircleButton:
    def __init__(Self, canvas, x, y, *, anchor="nw", command, **kwargs):
        # creo la imagen en x, y con el anchor dado por el usuario.
        # Si quieres que el centro del botón esté en ese punto, pasa el argumento anchor="center".
        Self.id = canvas.create_image(x, y, anchor=anchor, **kwargs)

        # Creo el atributo canvas y guardo el canvas allí, para poder usarlo después. Los objetos en el canvas se modifican usando métodos del canvas.
        Self.canvas = canvas

        # Creo el atributo command y guardo la función asociada al botón allí.
        # Puedes cambiar este atributo cuando quieras para que se ejecute una función diferente.
        Self.command = command

        # Hago que cada vez que el usuario hace clic en la imagen (inclusive la parte transparente)
        # se llame a la función encargada de llamar a la función asociada con el boton.
        canvas.tag_bind(Self.id, "<Button-1>", Self.call)

    def call(Self, event):
        return Self.command()

def button_command():
    print("hola mundo")


canvas = Canvas(v, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

fondo = PhotoImage(file="fondo.png")
fondoid = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=fondo)

# Aquí creo un entry en el canvas.
# El verdadero proposito de esta sección es demostrar como poner un widget de tkinter dentro de un canvas.
# El argumento window es el que recibe que widget se ubicará en en canvas.
widget=Entry(canvas)
canvas.create_window(50, 50, anchor="nw", window=widget)


button = PhotoImage(file="button.png")
CircleButton(canvas, 100, 100, command=button_command, anchor="center", image=button)

v.mainloop()
```

#### Bonus: No poder hacer clic fuera del circulo

Es posible que ahora me digas "pero no quiero que el usuario haga clic fuera del circulo y que así se aprete el botón. Como puedo evitarlo?"
La respuesta es: Matematicas hijo!

Suponiendo que la forma del boton es un circulo perfecto, para que un punto esté dentro de un circulo, la distancia entre este punto y el centro del circulo debe ser menor o igual al radio de dicho circulo.
Y asumiendo que `largo imagen = alto imagen = diametro circulo` obtener el radio del circulo es sencillo. De la inecuación:

```
distancia(lugar donde se hizo clic, centro del circulo) <= radio del circulo
```

Sale:

```
distancia(lugar donde se hizo clic, centro del circulo) <= (largo o alto imagen)/2
```

El modulo math ofrece buenas herramientas para calcular la distancia:

Luego de agregar al principio de tu código `import math`, reemplaza el método call de mi clase por esto:

```
def call(Self, event):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = Self.canvas.bbox(Self.id)

    radius = (x2 - x1)//2
    
    # Si usas python < 3.8 o quieres que tu código sea compatible con versiones inferiores de python
    # cambia esta linea por if(math.hypot(event.x-x1-radius, event.y-y1-radius) <= radius):
    if(math.dist((event.x, event.y), (x1+radius, y1+radius)) <= radius):
        # llamo a la función asociada con el boton sin pasarle argumentos y devuelvo lo que devuelva dicha función.
        return Self.command()
```

#### Ventajas, desventajas y conclusión

**Ventajas**

- Puedes crear botones con transparencia.

**Desventajas**

- No puedes usar .grid ni .pack
- Crear un widget real dentro del canvas es un poco más complejo.

**Conclusión**
Si te doy mi opinion, si haces esto te vas a complicar las cosas y te vas a perder algunas facilidades de Tkinter solo por darle al usuario una GUI con un botón circular. Mi recomendación es que uses un fondo de un solo color o un botón cuadrado.

#### Lecturas recomendadas

- https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas-methods.html
- https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas.html
- https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/math.html#math.dist

Comment: Gracias! Pero tienes razon, hay mas desventajas que ventajas, asique encontrare una alternativa. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Es un placer c: Si encuentras una alternativa, podrías publicarla aquí en tu pregunta para aquellos que la vean en tu futuro! Además, tengo curiosidad de que harás.